# Cannot index enum type with Hibernate Search MassIndexer

Tags: hibernate-search

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "asset")
@Indexed(index = "asset")
@Analyzer(impl = IKAnalyzer.class)

public class Asset {

    @Column(name = "asset_name", length = 128, nullable = false)
    @Field(name = "asset_name", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    private String assetName;

    @Column(name = "type", length = 32, nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    @Field(name = "type", index = Index.TOKENIZED, store = Store.YES)
    private AssetTypeEnum type;
}
```

This is my configuration of hibernate search. The AssetTypeEnum is Enum type. I want to index the existed data in database. This is the code

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
Transaction tx = fullTextSession.beginTransaction();
fullTextSession.createIndexer(Asset.class)
    .batchSizeToLoadObjects(25)
    .cacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)
    .threadsToLoadObjects(5)
    .threadsForSubsequentFetching(20)
    .startAndWait();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

It has no problem when I create a new asset, the asset can index auto. But I can not index with the enum type for the existed data in db. and if I remove the enum type it can work. 
Does anyone meet this problem? thank you.

Comment: "But I can not index with the enum type for the existed data in db" - why not? What is your problem? Do you get an exception or what else is the problem?

Comment: "AssetTypeEnum" is Enum type. When I create a new object of asset, it will create index for "AssetTypeEnum". I want to create index for the exist data in database, but it can't create index for "AssetTypeEnum", there is no exception.
And now I changed "AssetTypeEnum" from "Enum" type to "String".

Comment: How do you know it was not indexed? Did you inspect the index via Luke or do you try to query?